# TFS Hosted Build Controller - Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets not found

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops, t4

I've been debugging an issue for a day now and can't seem to figure it out. Perhaps someone else has run into something similar and can shed some light?

We've configured all T4 templates within a project in our solution to run when the project is built, as in *shift-ctrl-b*. This works great - it required us to add this import statement to the project .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"/>
```

We've set up continuous integration through Visual Studio 2012 and cloud TFS (tfs.visualstudio.com). When our solution is being built on TFS' hosted controller, we keep receiving the following error:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

On our dev machines, the file exists and thus the problem seems to be that the file doesn't exist on the hosted build server.

If we're correct with this assumption, is there a workaround to this issue besides installing our own TFS build server?

Answer (score 6):

I doubt the hosted  build servers have Visual Studio 2010 (v10.0) on them.

You can get a list of what is currently installed on the hosted build servers [here](http://listofsoftwareontfshostedbuildserver.azurewebsites.net/), Tarun Arora has more details [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2013/03/08/list-of-software-on-tfs-service-hosted-build.aspx).

For your problem, try version `11.0` (for VS2012) instead:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)
    \Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"/>
```

A better approach would be to use the `VisualStudioVersion` MSBuild property:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)
    \Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"/>
```

This will ensure that future updates to the Hosted Build Servers do not impact your code.
Have a read up [here](http://sedodream.com/2012/08/19/VisualStudioProjectCompatabilityAndVisualStudioVersion.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I originally used v11.0 and was still receiving the same error.

Comment: Yeah  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TextTemplating\v10.0\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />  is not working for me as well

Comment: I and Tarun Arora have developed a Visual Studio extension to get software installed on the hosted build servers. This helps you to view the details within Visual Studio. It works for Visual Studio 2012/2013.

Download it from here:

- [Avanade Extensions for VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/591f2516-9aec-4892-be08-53c1d63bc5a1)
- [Avanade Extensions for VS2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d5a90434-0e7f-4751-910f-b7df1450cf99)

Comment: Nice to use `v$(VisualStudioVersion)` but TextTemplating can't be find for VS2013

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some files are missing. :) So I was at the same situation. Here is the solution.

The correct solution is to install

**Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visualization & Modeling SDK**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23025

It creates the folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TextTemplating
and the files
Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets and others

**Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Visualization & Modeling SDK**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30680

It creates the folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TextTemplating
and the files
Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets and others

Enjoy! ;)

P.S. Somehow **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visualization & Modeling SDK** creates the folder here

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TextTemplating\v10.0

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets` file comes with overhead you probably don't need (*Modeling SDK for Microsoft Visual Studio*). You can most likely get away with a simple NuGet package that transforms on build (using *TextTransform.exe*): [Clarius.TransformOnBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Clarius.TransformOnBuild/).

For more information see the author's [blog post](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-transform-t4-templates-on-build-without-installing-a-visual-studio-sdk/).